# "Теоретик из тебя такой себе" — корректно ли такое предложение?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

В предложении: "Получается, что теоретик из тебя такой себе", нужно ли ставить дефис перед "такой себе"? Вообще, корректно ли выглядит данное предложение или же правильней будет "получается, что из тебя такой себе теоретик", либо же словосочетание "такой себе" неправильно и следует заменить его на "так себе"?

Answer (score 4):

1. Мне кажется, что в предложении может быть интонационное тире, которое ставится между любыми членами предложения, ― для выделения, подчеркивания сказанного.
2. В этом предложении по смыслу правильно говорить ***так себе*.**

**Получается, что теоретик из тебя ― так себе.**

*― Не веришь? (…)

― Не-а. Артист из тебя ― так себе.*
А. Рудаков. Война

В большом толковом словаре:
[ТАК СЕБЕ](https://slovar.cc/rus/tolk/114350.html)
**I** *нареч. качеств.-обстоят. разг.*
1. Не в сильной, не в высокой степени; не очень, не особенно, не слишком.
отт. Неважно, посредственно.
2. Употребляется как несогласованное определение.
**II** *предик. разг.*
**Оценочная характеристика кого-либо или чего-либо как ничем не выделяющихся, не отличающихся какими-либо достоинствами.**

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, дефис - это часть слова:

> Дефи́с (от нем. divis «соединительный знак, знак деления», от лат.
>   divisio «[раз]деление»), чёрточка (‐) — небуквенный орфографический
>   знак русской и многих других письменностей. Графически тождествен со
>   знаком переноса.

Речь может идти только о тире.

Не нужно предложению никакого тире.

Словосочетание "такой себе" (но не всегда) в данном случае некорректно.

*Так себе* - устойчивое сочетание (фразеологизм). У него два близких значения:

> **1.** *прил., пренебр.* не очень хороший, посредственный ◆ З*а после́дние го́ды че́рез ру́ки Скварыша прошло́ их нема́ло, бу́дущих
>   кандида́тов нау́к: бы́ли спосо́бные, бы́ли та́к себе, не ши́бко.* В.
>   В. Быков, «Бедные люди», 1998 г. ◆ *Ма́йка, руба́шка, носки́ ― всё это
>   бы́ло та́к себе, не сли́шком но́вым и далеко́ не чи́стым.* Александр
>   Житинский, «Лестница», 1972 г.
>
> **2.** *наречие, пренебр.* не очень хорошо, посредственно ◆ *Да и свой маркси́зм они зна́ли так себе.* А. А. Зиновьев, «Русская судьба,
>   исповедь отщепенца», 1988—1998 г. ◆ *От двух до пяти́ Нежда́нов сиде́л
>   у себя́ в ко́мнате, писа́л пи́сьма в Петербу́рг ― и чу́вствовал себя́…
>   та́к себе: ску́ки не́ было, не́ было и тоски́; натя́нутые не́рвы
>   понемно́жку смягча́лись.* И. С. Тургенев, «Новь», 1877 г.

---

[Пример употребления](http://knizhnik.org/andrej-rubanov/psihodel/3) *такой себе:*

> Нет, он не костолом с двумя извилинами. Умница, само спокойствие.
>   Такой себе самурай немногословный.

Или ещё, [из Брэдбери](http://raybradbury.ru/library/story/45/11/1/):

> Просто такой себе плюгавенький докторишка. Пытается помочь. Мьюниган и
>   его банка хлебных палочек. Смешно.

Comment: В литературных примерах выражение "такой себе" имеет смысл "_этакий (=своего рода)_", т. е. оно не произведено от выражения "так себе", которое добавляет _посредственную оценку_ (= "средней паршивости" и т. п.).

Comment: Я же сказала: *Словосочетание "такой себе" (но не всегда) в данном случае некорректно*. А литература - как пример употребления.

Answer (score 2):

1) **Так себе** — в роли  определения: пренебр. не очень хороший, посредственный.

*Получается, что теорЕтик из тебя / тАк себе.*

Можно обойтись без интонационного тире, здесь и так делается пауза.

**2) Такой себе** — усиление оценки, но не сама оценка.

Можно сказать: *Такой себе сомнительный ты теоретик*.

Пример: **Такой себе шерстистый господинчик** некрупной комплекции...[Дина Рубина. (2001)]